# Inverses of Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$. Let $H'<G'$.

Show the set $H=\{g\in G \ | \ \phi(g) \in H'\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. (I have done this, but its part 1 of the question)

Prove that if $H'$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
I know that you have to show that for any $g$ in $G$ that $ghg^{-1}=h$ or $gH=Hg$. I dont see how the normality of $H'$ and $G'$ help in this case.

Comment: We don't have to show that $ghg^{-1}=h$. To prove normality, we only need to show that $ghg^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: but $h\in H$, so thats the same thing

Comment: It is not the same thing. The statement $ghg^{-1}\in H$ just says that $ghg^{-1}$ is equal to some element of $H$, but not necessarily to this particular $h$. It is possible that $ghg^{-1}=h'$ where $h'$ is some other element of $H$. There is no guarantee that $ghg^{-1}=h$ for every $h\in H$, and $g\in G$. That would be indeed true if $H$ were contained in the centre of the group.

Comment: okay, thank you for clarify that actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h\in H$ and $g\in G$. We want to show that $ghg^{-1}\in H$. So let's compute
$\phi(ghg^{-1})$:

$$
\phi(g h g^{-1}) = \phi(g) \cdot \phi(h) \cdot \phi(g^{-1})
=\phi(g) \cdot \underbrace{\phi(h)}_{\in H'} \cdot \phi(g)^{-1} \in H'
$$
because $H'$ is normal in $G'$. But this precisely shows that $ghg^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

"Intuitive" explanation:
Normal subgroups and kernels are the same thing. Any kernel is normal and any normal subgroup $N \leq G$ is the kernel of the quotient map $\pi :G \to G/N$.

A kernel of a map $\phi : H \to G$ is by definition $\phi^{-1}\{0\}$.

Now suppose $N \leq G$ is a normal subgroup.

$\phi^{-1}(N) = \phi^{-1}(\pi^{-1}\{0\})$ = $(\pi \circ \phi)^{-1}\{0\}$

Therefore $\phi^{-1}(N)$ is a kernel, and so normal.